# Auth user Django in another database

Tags: django, authentication

In the same project I have some apps that should store data in the localhost database and some in a remote database.

I created a `routers.py` file and imported it into my `settings.py`. I also defined 2 databases in my settings file. Is this the correct one?

On some models/class I set `app_label = 'remote_db'` where I need to write data to the remote database.

part of `settings.py`

```py
DATABASES={
    'default':{
        ...
    },
    'remote_db':{
        ...
    }
}
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['smart.routers.AccessRouter',]
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.SmartUser'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

part of `users/models.py`

```py
class SmartUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'remote_db'
```

When i try `run makemigrations users` i get the following error:

> AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
>   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'users.SmartUser' that has not been installed

Answer (score 0):

If you have tables/models that will exist elsewhere, you need to tell Django that they are not managed models.

Something like this in your `models.py`:

```
class SomeClass(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column="id", primary_key=True)
    ...other attributes...

    class Meta(object):
        db_table = "your_table_for_this_model"
        managed = getattr(settings, "UNDER_TEST", False)
```

I use a global variable called 'UNDER_TEST', so that when running our tests django will manage the models and create the test-tables. You might not have to do that if your database allows creation of test tables. Our database is tightly managed and creation of test-tables is prohibited so this workaround is what we use to ensure we can create/run tests to keep our code covered/tested.

In your case where it's just a `User` model (we also have it in a separate db with it's own table) we have it like this:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
...our attributes...

class Meta:
    db_table = "ourApp_user"
```

That's it as far as specialty stuff for our `User` model.

In our settings we have the same as you, but we do not use `DATABASE_ROUTERS`

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

"default": {
    "ENGINE": "sql_server.pyodbc",
    "NAME": os.environ.get("default_NAME"),
    "HOST": os.environ.get("default_HOST"),
    "USER": os.environ.get("default_USER"),
    "PASSWORD": os.environ.get("default_PASSWORD"),
    "PORT": os.environ.get("default_PORT"),
    "OPTIONS": {
        "host_is_server": True,
        "driver": "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server",
    },
    "TEST": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "default-db.sqlite3"),
    },
},
"other_db": {
    "ENGINE": "sql_server.pyodbc",
    "NAME": os.environ.get("other_db_NAME"),
    "HOST": os.environ.get("other_db_HOST"),
    "USER": os.environ.get("other_db_USER"),
    "PASSWORD": os.environ.get("other_db_PASSWORD"),
    "PORT": os.environ.get("other_db_PORT"),
    "OPTIONS": {
        "host_is_server": True,
        "driver": "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server",
    },
    "TEST": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "other-db.sqlite3"),
    },
},
```

Try removing `app_label` and putting in the `db_table`, or leave `app_label` and put in `db_table` to tell it specifically which table it should look at.

Only put `managed=False` if it's a table you will be populating by other means and if you don't want Django to manage the data inside it (for example: if you have a script living somewhere else that populates a specific table your app needs to reference).